# Unhandled promise rejection after compiling from typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have VS2015 project where I'm using typescript (ES5 with AMD).
My main.ts file looks:

```
import {Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework';

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging();
    aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot());
}
```

But when I compile it, I get:

```
Unhandled promise rejection Error: define is not a function Error loading https://localhost/Web/dist/main.js at execute (https://localhost/Web/dist/main.js:7:13)
```

which is:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
```

Don't understand.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> define is not a function

As soon as you do `import` / `export` at the root level of you file, your file becomes a *module* and you need to have the corresponding module loader ([more](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html))

In your case it seems you are compiling with `--module amd`, and I recommend looking into using [`requirejs`](http://requirejs.org/) which is the most popular implementation of AMD.

**PS:** I personally swear by webpack / `--module commonjs` / NPM.